# Linear Regression shows the result with all categorical options in R

Tags: r, categorical-data

I run a simple linear regression: score against students' family social status (categorical variable: rich, middle, and poor) and students' parents' generation (generation boomers, generation X, and generation Y) and other numerical variables.

What I expect for the result is to have 2 (3-1 for social status) and 2 (3-1 for generation). However, the result shows me all categorical options for these two variables (3 and 3). What I understand is that R automatically discards one group in the estimation. Also, I check the original data, there are 3 groups for both variables.

What am I missing here? Thank you

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Can you show some code output and example data, and explicitly state what you aren't understanding about it? What do you mean by 3-1 or 3 and 3?

Comment: I agree with the comment above. Post your regression output and you'll get some answers.

Comment: can you post the code and output?

Comment: Thank you guys, I found the error because I put -1 in the regression.

Answer (score 1):

Although you found your coding error, I am still going to answer your question: "What am I missing here?"

You are right in that you should expect 2 of the 3 groups to be printed in the output, but R does not 'automatically discard one group in the estimation.' The 'group' that isn't named in your output is embedded within the intercept. For example, if your groups are GroupA, GroupB, and Group C, but your model results only show GroupB and GroupC, then the estimate for GroupB tells you how GroupB differs from GroupA, and the estimate for GroupC tells you how that group differs from GroupA, which is found within the intercept.

If you want to change the reference level of factors you can use `relevel()` (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/relevel) to pick a different group that will go into the intercept. I believe that R does this alphabetically, so the other way to do it would be to rename your groups so that the group you want to be in the intercept comes first in the alphabet (although this is probably considered worse coding practice).

Comment: Thank you. It is helpful for me to choose the group base for the comparison.